# iOS & FCM: Force Refresh Tokens

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does anyone know how to force refresh the registration token generated by FCM? I have only recently tried to migrate my project from GCM to FCM.

The documentation on the Firebase site mentions generating a token using:

```
// Get the default token
// The first time you call this, the token may not be available, in which case
// the SDK returns nil.
// Once the token is fetched from the server, the SDK posts a token refresh
// notification that you can listen for in order to access the new token.

NSString *token = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
```

But it looks like I'm only getting the token that was originally generated when I call `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()`

Answer (score 1):

If the Instance ID has become invalid, the app can request a new one and send it to the app server. To prove ownership of Instance ID and to allow servers to access data or services associated with the app, call [FIRInstanceID tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:options:handler].

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/interface_f_i_r_instance_i_d

Answer (score 0):

It might be coming late, but anyone else can refer my answer if it is of any help. I agree with @mKane, but I want to add something more to his answer.
If you have reset the instanceID or deleted the token, you can can call

```
if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderId scope:kFIRInstanceIDScopeFirebaseMessaging options:_registrationOptions handler:^(NSString * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    // Fetch the token or error
}];
```

If token comes nil, then wait for token in "tokenRefreshNotification" method, which will be called automatically if the token is nil in [FIRInstanceID tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:options:handler]. You can then catch the token in "tokenRefreshNotification" method and make use of it.

For how to use this method, please refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39742070/2959346)

Answer (score 0):

In swift 5 to force refresh the token I do:

```
InstanceID.deleteID(InstanceID.instanceID())(handler: {_ in})
```

As docs say: 
This method also triggers a request to fetch a new Instance ID and Firebase Messaging scope token. Please listen to kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification when the new ID and token are ready.

Then to get new token, just do as usual:

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
if error == nil{
    let newToken = result.token
    }
}
```