# How to get FCMToken in Firebase on ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As mentioned in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) we can retrieve FCMToken as follows.

```
NSString *fcmToken = [FIRMessaging messaging].FCMToken;
NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
```

However above returns compile time error `Property 'FCMToken' not found on object of type 'FIRMessaging *'`.

How to get FCMToken?

Comment: I am able to use the above lines without compile time issues. Are you sure  'Firebase/Messaging' framework is integrated in your project ?

Comment: Try using NSString *fcmToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
Let me know the result

Comment: I hope it is wise to mark my answer as correct if it worked for you. It might help others as well to see the correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using :

`NSString *fcmToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];`

For more information on this, please follow: [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39742070/2959346/)